# HTML block element overflowing its parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm encountering a weird (maybe not) behaviour that I want to avoid because the end result is a horrible user experience. To help you understand the problem I put together the code snippet below.

```js
var counter;
var counterDisplay;
var intervalRef;

window.onload = function(){
console.log("loading");
 counter = 11;
 counterDisplay = document.getElementById("spCounter");
  
  intervalRef = setInterval(tickHandler, 1000);
};

function tickHandler(){
    
    counter--;
    counterDisplay.innerHTML = counter.toString();
    
    
  if(counter == 0){
      stop();
        return;
    }
}

function stop(){
 clearInterval(intervalRef);
  document.getElementById("daddyLongLegs").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:16px;
}
.page-wrapper{
  height:100%;
  background-color:#eee;
}
.growing-element{
  height:800px;
  display:none;
  margin: 100px 100px 0 100px;
  background-color:#ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="container-element">   
    
      <!--This element's height never changes once the page has been rendered-->
      <div>
          The hidden child element below will magically appear in: <span id="spCounter">10</span> seconds
      </div>
      
      <!--This element's height changes anytime after the page has been loaded-->
      <div id="daddyLongLegs" class="growing-element">
           Now you see me...
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code snippet is pretty simple, all the javascript does is to display a child element (`#daddyLongLegs`) after ten seconds. Make the "problem" more visual colored the parent element (`div.container-element`) different to the child element.

### Problem

Now, when the child element (`#daddyLongLegs`) is displayed after 10 seconds, it doesn't seem to "stretch" the parent element (`div.container-element`). This is not the behaviour I'd like to achieve. I would like the parent element to re-adjust its height when its contents change. However, it is important that the height of the parent element ALWAYS cover the whole document

### Question

How can I make the parent readjust its height once the content has changed? Is there a **pure css solution** to this?

Comment: use `min-height: 100%` instead of `height: 100%` on your `.page-wrapper`

Comment: @moped damn! Stupid me! Add that comment as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height), you can use `min-height` attribute instead of `height` so whenever your `<div>`'s child rises, it will extend parent as well

**so from my comment:**

> use `min-height: 100%` instead of `height: 100%` on your
>   `.page-wrapper`

Answer (score 3):

`.container-element` has a defined height of `100%`
If you remove that, or set it to `auto`, it should calculate the height based on its content.
Or you could change from `height` to `min-height`, which would calculate the height based on its content, but no shorter than 100% of its parent's height.

Answer (score -1):

Change height to 100% and margin to 0;

```js
var counter;
var counterDisplay;
var intervalRef;

window.onload = function(){
console.log("loading");
 counter = 5;
 counterDisplay = document.getElementById("spCounter");
  
  intervalRef = setInterval(tickHandler, 1000);
};

function tickHandler(){
    
    counter--;
    counterDisplay.innerHTML = counter.toString();
    
    
  if(counter == 0){
      stop();
        return;
    }
}

function stop(){
 clearInterval(intervalRef);
  document.getElementById("daddyLongLegs").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:16px;
}
.page-wrapper{
  height:100%;
  background-color:#eee;
}
.growing-element{
  height:100%;
  display:none;  
  background-color:#ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="container-element">   
    
      <!--This element's height never changes once the page has been rendered-->
      <div>
          The hidden child element below will magically appear in: <span id="spCounter">10</span> seconds
      </div>
      
      <!--This element's height changes anytime after the page has been loaded-->
      <div id="daddyLongLegs" class="growing-element">
           Now you see me...
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is absolutely different behaviour as requested